# IntelliJ Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle generate wrong Java executable

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

This is [JetBrains issue in YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-187071)

I have a Java project which is built with Gradle.
I'm using IntelliJ and I've turned on the `Build, Execution, Deployment => Build Tools => Gradle => Runner` - `Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle`.

The build is working great but when I run or debug the project IntelliJ show the following error produced by Gradle:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:run MyApp'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java''

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5m 57s
247 actionable tasks: 246 executed, 1 up-to-date
CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
```

The problem seems to be `error=206, The filename or extension is too long` but it's not clear which file exactly is too long.

Comment: Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've created clean Java project and there the delegate build/run works fine so it's probably something specific to the project and not to IntelliJ

Comment: @CrazyCoder can you help me understand what affect the build of the gralde script that try to execute the java program?

Comment: Try to open this Application Run Configuration and check if JRE option specified properly.

Comment: Hello @CrazyCoder I'm back on this issue. Since I cannot reproduce the problem on a minimal project but I do run into it deterministically in my project, hope can I try to diagnose the problem?

Comment: I'll be glad to post the resulting gradle file, if it will help

Comment: I have some updates, I've removed from the project everything besides the main class and now it runs just fine, so it looks like the path to java was not the source of the problem. I've updated the question to show the output. I now need to find a way to run Gradle with `--info` to hopefully get better details about what is the problem and not just that there was a problem.